# Css. Sharp gradient of 5 colors

Tags: css

Im in a bit of struggle with this. Im trying to create a gradient containing 5 different colors with sharp edges. No blending. So far i have manage do 2. Bur how to do 5? anyone that can help on this?

thanks!

css:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    rgba(white, 0.4)  25%,
    transparent       25%,
    transparent       50%,
    rgba(white, 0.4)  50%,
    rgba(white, 0.4)  75%,
    transparent       75%,
    transparent
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,white 0%, white 20%, red 20%, red 40%, orange 40%, orange 60%, blue 60%, blue 80%, black 80%, black 100%);
```

**Update**

For changing the direction, just specify the starting edge:

- top left
- top
- top right
- right
- bottom right
- bottom
- bottom left
- left

or pass it an angle in degrees:
e.g: 45deg, 68deg, ...

Comment: You bet it is! Thank you.

Comment: Hm, its not really doing the job. its renders many squares containing the gradient. But i want it to cover the whole element instead. ill see if i can set up a fiddle.

Comment: Hi, set up a fiddle. So what i want is this but with 5 colors.

http://jsfiddle.net/7rr9hv3z/7/